# Flutter create table without columns

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from Firebase onto a table, this means the DataRow will be dynamic.

How do I create the table with only a `DataRow()`, without `DataColumn()`. I want to do this because I created a `ListView.builder` and put the firebase data in a table form. But I can't create the table without the DataColumn().

Please help.

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collectionGroup(widget.asADriverCollection)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(
              widget.errorString,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final info = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              final date = info.get("DepartureDate");
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedUser = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  });
                },
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: screenWidth * 0.05,
                      child: Text("${index + 1}"),
                    ),
                    DataTable(
                      columns: [], //I don't want to add this part of the table
                      rows: [
                        DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(date))])
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }),
      ),
```

Or is there a different way of having the table with static Columns and dynamic Rows from the database

Answer (score 1):

Since the columns are mandatory, how about creating empty `Text` widgets for the columns?

You would generate the number of columns needed (based on `snapshot.data!.docs.length`) and then render an empty `Text` widget:

```dart
columns: List.generate(snapshot.data.!docs.length, (index) => DataColumn(label: Text(''))),
```

You might also want to consider removing the Table's divider since there are no columns, which an be done through `dividerThickness`:

```dart
DataTable(
            dividerThickness:
                0.00000000001, 
            columns: List.generate(snapshot.data!.length, (index) => DataColumn(label: Text(''))),
            rows: [
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text('Cell 1')),
                DataCell(Text('Cell 2')),
              ]),
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text('Cell 3')),
                DataCell(Text('Cell 4')),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
```